# ASP: Database integration problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting

I integrated my database in my web application. Previously I was just referring it to `SQL server 2008` by defining a connection. Everything worked fine data was being fetched, calculations are done.

Now when i integrated my database in the web application, problems arose.

```
    Dim cost3 As Double
    cost3 = Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Item(0)(0).ToString
```

The problem is with this the **error** says: `Cannot Convert type String "" to double`. Before no such problem showed.

Any ideas ??
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim cost3 As Double = 0
cost3 = Double.TryParse(Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Item(0)(0).ToString, cost3)
```

Answer (score 1):

.ToString() will give you a String object. You are trying to assign a String to a Double.

Try

```
cost3 = (Double)Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Item(0)(0)
```

or

```
cost3 = Convert.ToDouble( Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Item(0)(0) )
```

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider) at System.Convert.ToDouble(Object value)`

Comment: If your data can be null, you'll need to add some error checking to your code to check for null values and populate cost3 accordingly. The information here is meant to help you, not do all of your work.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I didn't meant to do all of my work. what I did is showing you the error and asking for any ideas. Anyways thanks again